# How to call a method after creating a new instance of a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

Im trying to call the send_text method from my sendtextcontroller:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class SendtextController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end


def send_text_message
     number_to_send_to = current_user.cell_phone

    account_sid = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    auth_token = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    twilio_phone_number = "(954)-333-3333"

       @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
      :to => number_to_send_to
      :body => "Your bill has been added")
  end
end
```

In my Billscontroller after i create a new bill:

```
class BillsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bill, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def create
    @bill = Bill.new(bill_params)
    #sets new bill equal to the id of the current user signed in.
    @bill.user_id = current_user.id


    respond_to do |format|
      if @bill.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bill, notice: 'Bill was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bill }

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ive tried calling the send_text_message in many different places throughout the create method in the Billscontroller and have had no luck when i create a new bill on my localhost. Any suggestions? What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want a SendTextMessage controller and not just a helper method or some other type of class to handle sending the text message?

Comment: Im not entirely sure no... Twilio tells you to create that controller to to send out going SMS. Dont think its necessary though... What do you suggest?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to combine the functionality of the two controllers

Comment: Isnt the purpose of a helper method to make a method defined in the controller available in the view?

Comment: Are you using the SendTextMessage controller anywhere else at all? If not, you could just move that send_text_message method to your BillsController and you would have no problem calling it from your create action.

Comment: @philnash Ok Thanks. If i move the send_text_message method to the bills controller, where in the bill create method would i actually call send_text_message ?

Comment: I would guess you want to send the text if the bill saves correctly, so I would add `send_text_message` on the line after `if @bill.save`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio has use cases where you want to create controllers to use their REST API. This is mainly beacuse of how the buisness logic is laid out in relation to their example applications. In this case, as long as you loaded the twilio gem, you can just create a helper method in your controller and invoke send_text_message from your BillsController. All the gem does is provide you with a wrapper so that you can perform a `GET`/`POST` requests to their servers.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. So i would create the helper method in my application controller?

Comment: Yep, just create the helper method in the controller. Please let me know if you have any other questions!